# Sounds and graphics aren't working properly after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, steam, microphone

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and my sound doesn't work. I have tried "force reload ASLA" which I have read on another site and this hasn't worked. I wonder if it is because the drivers aren't correct? This would explain why a game on steam doesn't load either (if the graphics drivers aren't correct). Also, the microphone doesn't work when I use Skype.

Does anybody have any solutions to how I can check if the drivers are the correct ones or where I can find them if not? Alternatively, does anybody have any other ideas why the sound/mic/game isn't working?